# better and easy way to find who spoke top 10 anger words from conversation text

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, grepl, tidytext, sentimentr

I have a dataframe that contains variable 'AgentID', 'Type', 'Date', and 'Text' and a subset is as follows:

```
structure(list(AgentID = c("AA0101", "AA0101", "AA0101", "AA0101", 
                            "AA0101"), Type = c("PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS"), Date = c("4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019"),  Text = c("I am on social security XXXX and I understand it can not be garnished by Paypal credit because it's federally protected.I owe paypal {$3600.00} I would like them to cancel this please.", 
                        "My XXXX account is being reported late 6 times for XXXX per each loan I was under the impression that I was paying one loan but it's split into three so one payment = 3 or one missed payment would be three missed on my credit,. \n\nMy account is being reported wrong by all credit bureaus because I was in forbearance at the time that these late payments have been reported Section 623 ( a ) ( 2 ) States : If at any time a person who regularly and in the ordinary course of business furnishes information to one or more CRAs determines that the information provided is not complete or accurate, the furnisher must promptly provide complete and accurate information to the CRA. In addition, the furnisher must notify all CRAs that received the information of any corrections, and must thereafter report only the complete and accurate information. \n\nIn this case, I was in forbearance during that tie and document attached proves this. By law, credit need to be reported as of this time with all information and documentation",
                        "A few weeks ago I started to care for my credit and trying to build it up since I have never used my credit in the past, while checking my I discover some derogatory remarks in my XXXX credit report stating the amount owed of {$1900.00} to XXXX from XX/XX/2015 and another one owed to XXXX for {$1700.00} I would like to address this immediately and either pay off this debt or get this negative remark remove from my report.", 
                        "I disputed this XXXX  account with all three credit bureaus, the reported that it was closed in XXXX, now its reflecting closed XXXX once I paid the {$120.00} which I dont believe I owed this amount since it was an fee for a company trying to take money out of my account without my permission, I was charged the fee and my account was closed. I have notified all 3 bureaus to have this removed but they keep saying its correct. One bureau is showing XXXX closed and the other on shows XXXX according to XXXX XXXX, XXXX shows a XXXX, this account has been on my report for seven years", 
                        "On XX/XX/XXXX I went on XXXX XXXX  and noticed my score had gone down, went to check out why and seen something from XXXX XXXX  and enhanced recovery company ... I also seen that it had come from XXXX and XXXX dated XX/XX/XXXX, XX/XX/XXXX, and XX/XX/XXXX ... I didnt have neither one before, I called and it the rep said it had come from an address Im XXXX XXXX, Florida I have never lived in Florida ever ... .I have also never had XXXX XXXX  nor XXXX XXXX  ... I need this taken off because it if affecting my credit score ... This is obviously identify theft and fraud..I have never received bills from here which proves that is was not done by me, I havent received any notifications ... if it was not for me checking my score I wouldnt have known nothing of this" )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

First, I found out the top 10 anger words using the following:

```
library(tm)
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
library(sentimentr)
library(wordcloud)
library(ggplot2)

CS <- function(txt){
  MC <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
  SW <- stopwords('english')
  MC <- tm_map(MC, tolower)
  MC<- tm_map(MC,removePunctuation)
  MC <- tm_map(MC, removeNumbers)
  MC <- tm_map(MC, removeWords, SW)
  MC <- tm_map(MC, stripWhitespace)
  myTDM <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(MC))
  v <- sort(rowSums(myTDM), decreasing=TRUE)
  FM <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq=v)
  row.names(FM) <- NULL
  FM <- FM %>%
    mutate(word = tolower(word)) %>%
    filter(str_count(word, "x") <= 1)
  return(FM)
}

DF <- CS(df$Text)

# using nrc
nrc <- get_sentiments("nrc")
# create final dataset
DF_nrc = DF %>% inner_join(nrc)
```

And the I created a vector of top 10 anger words as follows:

```
TAW <- DF_nrc %>%
  filter(sentiment=="anger") %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  summarize(freq = mean(freq)) %>%
  arrange(desc(freq)) %>% 
  top_n(10) %>%
  select(word)
```

Next what I wanted to do is to find which were the 'Agent'(s) who spoke these words frequently and rank them. But I am confused how we could do that? Should I search the words one by one and group all by agents or is there some other better way. What I am looking at as a result, something like as follows:

```
AgentID  Words_Spoken             Rank
A0001  theft, dispute, money    1
A0001  theft, fraud,            2
.......
```

Comment: When I run `DF <- CS(df$Text)` I get error `Error in stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  argument \`str\` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to) `

Comment: @RonakShah - I am so sorry, not sure why this error. I created dput from my dataframe, so technically there should not be any issues. Or May be I forgot something in the code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but here's how you could count the words based on the line number:

```
library(stringr)

# write a new data.frame retaining the AgentID and Date from the original table
new.data <- data.frame(Agent = df$AgentID, Date = df$Date) 

# using a for-loop to go through every row of text in the df provided.  

for(i in seq(nrow(new.data))){ # i represent row number of the original df

  # write a temporary object (e101) that:
        ## do a boolean check to see if the text from row i df[i, "Text"] the TAW$Word with stringr::str_detect function
        ## loop the str_detect with sapply so that the str_detect do a boolean check on each TAW$Word
        ## return the TAW$Word with TAW$Word[...]

  e101 <- TAW$word[sapply(TAW$word, function(x) str_detect(df[i, "Text"], x))] 

  # write the number of returned words in e101 as a corresponding value in new data.frame
  new.data[i, "number_of_TAW"] <- length(e101)

  # concatenate the returned words in e101 as a corresponding value in new data.frame
  new.data[i, "Words_Spoken"] <- ifelse(length(e101)==0, "", paste(e101, collapse=","))
}

new.data

#    Agent     Date number_of_TAW      Words_Spoken
# 1 AA0101 4/1/2019             0                  
# 2 AA0101 4/1/2019             0                  
# 3 AA0101 4/1/2019             2 derogatory,remove
# 4 AA0101 4/1/2019             3  fee,money,remove
# 5 AA0101 4/1/2019             1             theft
```

Comment: Superb! This gives me clue now what to do. sum of `number_of_TAW and Group by `Agent` should give me ranking. Thanks Adam. But it will really be helpful for others and me, if you could give some explanation on what you did here.

Comment: Edited with comments. Want to stress again that this is not an elegant solution. Nested loops tend to take a hit in performance. .

Comment: I agree but as long as it is for dynamically selected (as in case of shiny app), I think this would not effect me much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are more of a dplyr/tidyverse person, you can take an approach using some dplyr verbs, after converting your text data to a tidy format.

First, let's set up some example data with several speakers, one of whom speaks *no* anger words. You can use `unnest_tokens()` to take care of most of your text cleaning steps with its defaults, such as splitting tokens, removing punctuation, etc. Then remove stopwords using `anti_join()`. I show using `inner_join()` to find the anger words as a separate step, but you could join these up into one big pipe if you like.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

my_df <- tibble(AgentID = c("AA0101", "AA0101", "AA0102", "AA0103"),
                Text = c("I want to report a theft and there has been fraud.",
                         "I have taken great offense when there was theft and also poison. It is distressing.",
                         "I only experience soft, fluffy, happy feelings.",
                         "I have a dispute with the hateful scorpion, and also, I would like to report a fraud."))

my_df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   AgentID Text                                                             
#>   <chr>   <chr>                                                            
#> 1 AA0101  I want to report a theft and there has been fraud.               
#> 2 AA0101  I have taken great offense when there was theft and also poison.…
#> 3 AA0102  I only experience soft, fluffy, happy feelings.                  
#> 4 AA0103  I have a dispute with the hateful scorpion, and also, I would li…

tidy_words <- my_df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, Text) %>%
  anti_join(get_stopwords()) 
#> Joining, by = "word"

anger_words <- tidy_words %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("nrc") %>%
               filter(sentiment == "anger"))
#> Joining, by = "word"

anger_words
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    AgentID word        sentiment
#>    <chr>   <chr>       <chr>    
#>  1 AA0101  theft       anger    
#>  2 AA0101  fraud       anger    
#>  3 AA0101  offense     anger    
#>  4 AA0101  theft       anger    
#>  5 AA0101  poison      anger    
#>  6 AA0101  distressing anger    
#>  7 AA0103  dispute     anger    
#>  8 AA0103  hateful     anger    
#>  9 AA0103  scorpion    anger    
#> 10 AA0103  fraud       anger
```

Now you now which anger words each person used, and the next step is to count them up and rank people. The [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package has fantastic support for exactly this kind of work. First you want to `group_by()` the person identifier, then calculate a couple of summarized quantities:

- the total number of words (so you can arrange by this)
- a pasted-together string of the words used

Afterwards, arrange by the number of words and make a new column that gives you the rank.

```r
anger_words %>%
  group_by(AgentID) %>%
  summarise(TotalWords = n(),
            WordsSpoken = paste0(word, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  arrange(-TotalWords) %>%
  mutate(Rank = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   AgentID TotalWords WordsSpoken                                       Rank
#>   <chr>        <int> <chr>                                            <int>
#> 1 AA0101           6 theft, fraud, offense, theft, poison, distressi…     1
#> 2 AA0103           4 dispute, hateful, scorpion, fraud                    2
```

Do notice that with this approach, you don't have a zero entry for the person who spoke no anger words; they get dropped at the `inner_join()`. If you want them in the final data set, you will likely need to join back up with an earlier dataset and use `replace_na()`.

<sup>Created on 2019-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why Julia is late to answer :)  you're the best! as always.